# Timeout Exception in Apache-Spark during program Execution

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-graphx, apache-spark-2.0

I am running a Bash Script in MAC. This script calls a spark  method written in Scala language for a large number of times. I am currently trying  to call this  spark method for 100,000 times using a for loop.

The code exits with the following exception after running a small number of iterations, around 3000 iterations.

```
org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeoutException: Futures timed out after [10 seconds]. This timeout is controlled by spark.executor.heartbeatInterval
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.org$apache$spark$rpc$RpcTimeout$$createRpcTimeoutException(RpcTimeout.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:59)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.apply(PartialFunction.scala:167)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEndpointRef.askWithRetry(RpcEndpointRef.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$reportHeartBeat(Executor.scala:518)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(Executor.scala:547)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Executor.scala:547)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Executor.scala:547)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1877)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anon$1.run(Executor.scala:547)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)

Exception in thread "dag-scheduler-event-loop" 16/11/22 13:37:32 WARN NioEventLoop: Unexpected exception in the selector loop.
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at io.netty.util.internal.MpscLinkedQueue.offer(MpscLinkedQueue.java:126)
    at io.netty.util.internal.MpscLinkedQueue.add(MpscLinkedQueue.java:221)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.fetchFromScheduledTaskQueue(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:259)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:346)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:357)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1047)
    at java.lang.String.replace(String.java:2180)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getFormattedClassName(Utils.scala:1728)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.RDDInfo$$anonfun$1.apply(RDDInfo.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.RDDInfo$$anonfun$1.apply(RDDInfo.scala:57)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.RDDInfo$.fromRdd(RDDInfo.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.StageInfo$$anonfun$1.apply(StageInfo.scala:87)
```

Can someone help please, is this error being caused because of a large number of calls to spark method?

Comment: it also show java out of space exception so can you once increase the memory and try it again

Comment: Are you prsisting data? With cache or something like that? Are you using Dataframe or RDD api?

Comment: yes I am using the RDD api. @ThiagoBaldim

Comment: Can you add the snipped of the code? Maybe it can be from your method.

Comment: @RamPrasadG I am still running it. I have very large dataset. Once it successfully completes without error I shall accept the answer. Last time the error occurred after a day of execution. thanks for the help

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Its `RpcTimeoutException` .. so `spark.network.timeout` (`spark.rpc.askTimeout`)  could be tuned with larger-than-default values in order to handle complex workload. You can start with these values and adjust accordingly to your workloads.
Please see [latest](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html)

> `spark.network.timeout`   120s    Default timeout for all network
>   interactions. This config will be used in place of
>   spark.core.connection.ack.wait.timeout,
>   spark.storage.blockManagerSlaveTimeoutMs,
>   spark.shuffle.io.connectionTimeout, spark.rpc.askTimeout or
>   spark.rpc.lookupTimeout if they are not configured.

Also consider increasing executor memory i.e `spark.executor.memory` and most imp thing is review your code, to check whether that is candidate for further optimization.

#### Solution :  value 600 is based on requirement

```
set by SparkConf: conf.set("spark.network.timeout", "600s")
set by spark-defaults.conf: spark.network.timeout 600s
set when calling spark-submit: --conf spark.network.timeout=600s
```

Comment: What would be the disadvantages of keeping a high value ? . Does it cause any side effects ?

Comment: @AmoghHuilgol :  I haven't checked that! but it is clear that large workload needs bit high value. you can try on your own and post as separate question and answer for this.

Comment: @AmoghHuilgol :Pls give feedback if you like the answer here :-)

Answer (score 5):

The above stack trace is also shown java heap space its OOM error so once try to increase the memory and run it and regarding timeout its rpc timeout so you can set **`spark.network.timeout`** with timeout value according to your need...

Answer (score 1):

pls  increase the executer memory  so that OOM will go away else make chnage in code so that your `RDD` wont have big memory foot print.

> --executer-memory = 3G

Answer (score 1):

Just increase the `spark.executor.heartbeatInterval` to 20s, the error says that.

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing this issue due to the executor memory.
Try increasing the memory to (x 2) so the containers don't time out while waiting on the remaining containers.

Answer (score 0):

For posterity: I was getting similar errors, but changing memory/timeout settings was not helping at all.

In my case the problem was that somebody was calling [`socket.setdefaulttimeout`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.setdefaulttimeout) in a library function that I was calling before creating the Spark session.  `setdefaulttimeout` affected *all* new sockets created after that point, including the socket that Spark used to communicate with YARN, so that connection would time out unexpectedly.

Needless to say, **don't do this**.