# How long will a spark job wait for resource from yarn when lack of resources?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

When a Spark job can't get enough resource to start, and it hang there to wait.

How long will it wait? How can I control the timeout for a hanging spark job?

Thanks

Comment: is this what youre looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40740750/timeout-exception-in-apache-spark-during-program-execution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under YARN, a job can hang indefinitely waiting for resources.  However, since large tasks are typically broken in smaller tasks they wouldn’t normally be blocked unless the smallest task exceeds the max container limit.